# CircleCI Code deploy orb cannot find file located in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, circleci

I am implementing a Blue/Green deployment using `aws-code-deploy` orb. My infrastructure is being implemented using terraform which consists of the following resources.

1. S3 bucket → stores the appspec.yml which is used to create the deployment.
2. VPC for networking ( It was easier to spin mine up for this demo. Too lazy to navigate the Legitscript networking lol )
3. An application Load balancer, 2 Listener Groups and 2 Target Groups. On initial deployment of infrastructure, go to EC2 → Target groups and you will see TG1 will have a healthy target associated with it but TG2 will not. It will change once we implement the Blue green deployment.
4. ECS  → A cluster, service and task definition will be available.
5. CodeDeploy → CodeDeploy application and deployment group.

This is my terraform file for S3 resource :-

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "blue-green-cd-ls"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "appspec" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
  key    = "appspec.yaml"
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/appspec.yaml.tpl", {
    task_definition_arn = var.task_definition_arn
  })
}
```

Which successfuly creates the S3 bucket with the appspec.yml file in it. I am trying to create a deployment using CircleCI and my config.yml looks like this :-

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.3
  aws-code-deploy: circleci/aws-code-deploy@2.0.0
jobs:
  deploy:
    executor: aws-cli/default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-cli/setup
      - aws-code-deploy/deploy-bundle:
          application-name: "blue-green"
          bundle-bucket: "blue-green-cd-ls"
          bundle-key: "appspec.yaml"
          deployment-group: "blue-green-ls"
          bundle-type: "YAML"
          deployment-config: "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"
workflows:
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy
```

But my deployment keeps on failing with the following error :-

```
Deployment failed!
{
    "deploymentInfo": {
        "applicationName": "blue-green",
        "deploymentGroupName": "*************",
        "deploymentConfigName": "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce",
        "deploymentId": "d-85LKXCPMJ",
        "revision": {
            "revisionType": "S3",
            "s3Location": {
                "bucket": "blue-green-cd-ls",
                "key": "appspec.yaml.YAML",
                "bundleType": "YAML"
            }
        },
        "status": "Failed",
        "errorInformation": {
            "code": "INVALID_REVISION",
            "message": "The AppSpec file cannot be located in the specified S3 bucket. Verify your AppSpec file is present and that the name and key value pair specified for your S3 bucket are correct. The S3 bucket must be in your current region"
```

I double checked and the S3 bucket is definitely in the right region i.e. us-east-1. Anyone has any ideas what might be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You don't specify the `aws-region` parameter when invoking [the `aws-cli/setup` command](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/aws-cli#commands-setup), so it'll take the value that you stored in the `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable. Did you assign the value `us-east-1` to that variable? Do you have "another" `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable declared in a context, and that'd be the one holding the correct value?

Comment: @yaningo Thank you for looking into it. Yes, i did specify `us-east-1` region when using `aws configure`. Even in my terraform, `us-east-1` is specified. Any other ideas?

Comment: What I meant is: do you have an [environment variable in your CircleCI project](https://circleci.com/docs/env-vars#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-project) called `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` to which you assigned the value `us-east-1`?

Comment: Yes, i do have that setup. And it's `us-east-1`.

Comment: Something I only just noticed: `"key": "appspec.yaml.YAML"`. Wouldn't that extra `YAML` be the reason causing: "The AppSpec file cannot be located [...]"? Shouldn't it be just `appspec.yaml`?

What's the outcome if you try:

- aws-code-deploy/deploy-bundle:
    application-name: "blue-green"
    bundle-bucket: "blue-green-cd-ls"
    bundle-key: "appspec"
    deployment-group: "blue-green-ls"
    bundle-type: "yaml"
    deployment-config: "CodeDeployDefault.ECSAllAtOnce"

Comment: Maybe i can try setting the key just as `appspec` instead of `appspec.yaml`  in my S3 terraform module because i noticed that extra yaml in there too.

Comment: Make sure to use lowercase for the `bundle-type` value: `bundle-type: "yaml"`.

Comment: @yaningo Sadly No success.

Comment: @yaningo I am starting to think there might be an issue with the CLI either. I couldn't even create it using the ` aws deploy create-deployment` command either. I can achieve the same using the UI. Idk it's weird. Thank you for helping though.

Comment: Indeed, could be that the AWS CLI is not properly configured _for some reason_ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Have you tried [SSH-ing into the build](https://circleci.com/docs/ssh-access-jobs), and running a simple command of the AWS CLI, like maybe `aws configure get region`?